# Add data to every child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So the situation is like this. Every User has a list of Tasks and some of these tasks are shared among different users. These users has there own separate copy of the shared task but with the same task Id. Now I want to add a commentSectionId for all these tasks. And obviously, tasks with the same task Id should have the same commentSectionId.
Now this can be done easily by querying the Main parent node and iterating over it and setting the values one by one. But I don't want to download the whole user Data. Is there any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add data to an existing node by creating a reference to that node and then calling `update(newData)` on it. E.g.

```
var ref = firebase.database.ref("/UserTasks/uidOfAUser/idOfATask");
ref.update({ comments: {
  "-Ldsfjklfdsgsd": {
    auth: "hiten pannu",
    text: "This is a comment"
  },
  "-Ldsfjklfdsgzz": {
    auth: "puf",
    text: "This is a response"
  }
});
```

As you can see this doesn't load the data of the task. But it does require that you know both the UID of the user and the ID of the task that you're trying to update.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Frank. But that's the real problem the user and task are not specific So, I have to traverse through all the users and tasks and check if that task is assigned with any comment id or not. If that is task is not having any commentSectionId I have to check in the local map if we assigned any commentSectionId to that task id or not.

Comment: I figured out two ways.
1. I maintain a RelationShip node in Firebase where I just map taskId with CommentSectionId
2. I Export the database run the logic described in above comment and import it in the firebase. As my customer base is around 5000 and all of them belong to same time zone. I don't think it will create much of a problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: The first approach sounds like a bi-directional data map, which is quite common in NoSQL databases. The second approach sounds like an ETL pipeline that then imports the data back again. That seems to have the risk of data changes while you're modifying the data in an external system, which seems like a bad idea. Then again: either can probably be made to work, which means it's a personal preference of what you're more familiar with and what you think will work best for your system going forward.